# Subset of $(l^{2},d_{2})$ is open

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Show that $A = \{\phantom{i}\{x_{n}\} \in l^{2} \hspace{2mm}:\hspace{2mm} |x_{n}| < 1, \forall \phantom{i}n \in \mathbb{N}\phantom{i} \}$  is open in $(l^{2},d_{2})$.
The $d_{2}$ metric is:

$$ d_2(x,y) = \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_{i} - y_{i}|^{2}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}. $$

I have started the proof as follows but I'm not seeing the choice of $\epsilon$ for this proof.

> To prove this equality, it suffices to show that $A \subset \text{Int}(A)$. So, let $\xi \in A$. We know that $|\xi_{i}| < 1$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $\epsilon =?? $. We claim that $B_{\epsilon}(\xi) \subset A$. So, let $x \in B_{\epsilon}(\xi)$. Thus, $d_{2}(x,\xi) < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

The key point is that, since $\forall x\in\ell^2,\ \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$, it must hold $$\xi\in A\implies \exists\, \alpha_\xi>0\ \ \forall n,\ \lvert \xi_n\rvert<1-\alpha_\xi$$

So, $\varepsilon=\alpha_\xi$ works, since it holds, in general, $$\forall n,\ \lvert x_n-y_n\rvert\le d_2(x,y)$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. That makes sense to me. Could you comment on my "proof" in progress? I don't think I know what I'm doing here. -- It suffices to show that $A \subset \text{Int}(A)$. Let $\xi \in A$. Then, $|\xi_{n}| < 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Note that for all $\xi$, there is a number $\alpha(\xi) > 0$ such that $|\xi_{n}| < 1 - \alpha(\xi)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So, let $\epsilon = \alpha(\xi)$. Then, we want to show that $B_{\alpha(\xi)}(\xi) \subset A$. Thus, let $x \in B_{\alpha(\xi)}(\xi)$ $\iff$ $d_{2}(x,\xi) < \alpha(\xi)$...

Comment: Your proof is not finished. You must show that, for $\xi\in A$, $$d(x,\xi)<\alpha_\xi\implies \forall n, \rvert x_n\lvert<1$$ I edited the question to include the key-point of this last passage.

Comment: I started from scratch. Is this getting any closer? Let $\xi \in A$. Note that for all $\xi \in A$, there is a positive number, call it $\tau(\xi)$, such that $|\xi_{n}| < 1 - \tau(\xi)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, set $\epsilon = \tau(\xi)$. Let $\omega \in A$. Then,
$ d_{2}(\omega,\xi) < \tau(\xi) \iff \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|\omega_{i} - \xi_{i}|^{2}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}} < \tau(\xi) < 1 - |\xi_{n}|$
This implies that $|\omega_{n}| < 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, $\omega \in \text{Int}(A)$. So, $A$ is open in $(l^{2},d_{2})$.

Comment: If you have an argument to justify "This implies", then it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Hint,for ${x_n},{y_n}$ belong to $l^2$,c=sup|$x_n|<1,$ let $\epsilon$=1-c,if||x-y||<$\epsilon$,then,|$x_n-y_n$|<$\epsilon$,any n.$

Comment: [Bad formatting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and, to be fair, you do not justify why $$(\forall n,\lvert x_n\rvert<1)\implies \sup_n \lvert x_n\rvert<1$$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli my latex skill is bad

Answer (score 1):

Still another possibility is to rewrite your set: 
$$
A=f^{-1}(0,1),$$
where 
$$
f(\boldsymbol{x})=\max_{j\ge 1} \lvert x_j\rvert,\qquad \boldsymbol{x}\in\ell^2$$
is a function 
$$
f\colon \ell^2\to [0, \infty).$$
If you show that $f$ is continuous then $A$ is open, being the preimage of an open set. But $f$ is actually a norm, and so it is continuous if and only if there exists a constant $C>0$ such that 
$$
f(\boldsymbol{x})\le C\lVert \boldsymbol x\rVert_{\ell^2}.$$
This last inequality holds with $C=1$, it should not be hard to see it.

P.S.: Why does this inequality imply that $f$ is continuous? Because one has the following: 
$$
|f(\boldsymbol x)-f(\boldsymbol y) |\le f(\boldsymbol x - \boldsymbol y) \le C\lVert \boldsymbol x -\boldsymbol y\rVert_{\ell^2}, $$
so $f$ is actually Lipschitz continuous.